# How to create a calendar event / appointment in Exchange Server 2003 without using Outlook?

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server

Is there any way to create - manipulate calendar events in Exchange Server 2003 ?
I'm using VB.NET 2005. I don't want to use MAPI because everytime I will have to type user name and passwords. Is there any other way ? I used redemption.dll but everytime I want to add for eg. a calendar event it displays the login screen.

Any suggestions ?

Appreciate your help

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check out WebDAV. Appearantly, there are some limitation in WebDAV with regards to recurring appointments, but the interface is simple and effective.

Check the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142661(EXCHG.65).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on a project to manipulate appointments (when I first started programming), and from VB, the easiest route to Exchange appointments at that time (avoiding MAPI) was using the Office Core & Outlook interop APIs named Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.dll & Interop.Outlook.dll. As this was for an application on a desktop machine you needed to have Outlook installed on the same box, but this may have changed since (was around 4-5 years ago).

Alternatively with the the CDO libraries (which wrap the MAPI APIs), I don't think you need Outlook installed and these are relatively easy (and much faster) to use. May have been superceeded by now however.

Just on a side note, an application called OutlookSpy proved invaluable at the time for inspecting exchange runtime objects.